# Cell next to rowspan cells height difference in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, chromium

I'm trying to build a table in HTML where there is one row with some generic information, followed by multiple rows of related detail data, followed by again a generic row, a set of detailed rows, etc.

The way I'm approaching it is that the cells in the generic row have a `rowspan` equal to the number of detail rows plus one. That way the detail rows get "pushed" to the right by the generic row.

The problem I have is when the generic row is higher than the detail row, for example because of multi-line contents, on Firefox the detail row gets a minimal height aligned to the bottom while on Chromium-based browsers the detail row has the same height as the generic row.

An example with just one detail row:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">left<br><br>1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">left<br><br>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>right1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In Firefox it looks like this:
[Firefox preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr42I.png)

In Chromium it looks like this:
[Chromium preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zZFg.png)

Ironically, when I add `style="height: 100%"` to the rows, the situation is reversed and in Firefox the right cell grows to the other row's height, while in Chromium its size gets minimized.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr style="height: 100%">
    <td rowspan="2">left<br><br>1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">left<br><br>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 100%">
    <td>right1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**I want to have the default Chromium behavior (the cell on the right using the same height as the rowspan cells) in both Firefox and Chromium.**

Though in my specific case, I would also accept it if I kind of get the same behavior as in Firefox in both browsers but with the cell aligned to the top rather than the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with every web browser. Try using normalize.css.

Under the hood, normalize.css does no magic. It just overrides some of the properties that the browser has set so as to make the HTML document the same throughout various browsers.
Be careful though, if you are also including another CSS document in your HTML document, the order of the positioning matters.

[Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

[image: Image of normalize.css]

Comment: Thanks. I just tried normalize.css, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to address this particular issue.